# JDialog is not showing up

Tags: java, jdialog

I have this problem over and over again when i call my JDialog class is not showing anything this is the code for the JDialog interface:

```
public JMovie() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    JDialog jmovie = new JDialog(f,"JMovie Dialog");
    jmovie.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    okbutton = new JButton("Ok");
    cancelbutton = new JButton("Cancel");
    title = new JLabel("Title", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    date = new JLabel("Date made on ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    price = new JLabel("Price", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    inputdate = new JLabel("dd/mm/yyyy");

    Ttitle = new JTextField(null, 15);
    TMadeon = new JTextField(null, 10);
    TPrice = new JTextField(null, 6);

    jp1 = new JPanel();
    jp2 = new JPanel();
    jp3 = new JPanel();
    jb = new JPanel();
    jl = new JPanel();

    okbutton.addActionListener(this);
    cancelbutton.addActionListener(this);


    Ttitle.setName("Title");
    TMadeon.setName("Date Made on");
    TPrice.setName("Price");

    jb.add(okbutton);
    jb.add(cancelbutton);

    title.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
    date.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
    price.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);

    JPanel south = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    south.add(jb, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JPanel west = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
    west.add(title,BorderLayout.WEST);
    west.add(date,BorderLayout.WEST);
    west.add(price,BorderLayout.WEST);

    JPanel center = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
    center.add(jp3,FlowLayout.LEFT);
    center.add(jp2,FlowLayout.LEFT);
    center.add(jp1,FlowLayout.LEFT);
    inputdate.setEnabled(false);

    jmovie.setSize(350, 150);
    jmovie.setLocation(300,300);
    jmovie.setVisible(true);

    jmovie.add(south);
    jmovie.add(west);
    jmovie.add(center);
}
```

This is the code of the interface JMovie DIalog and i call it here in another class.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if(event.getSource().equals(btnMAdd))
        {
            JMovie ne = new JMovie();
            ne.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

when i run it is showing this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntjux.png]

Comment: Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem. We should be able to copy/paste/compile and test.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some variables are correct, others are not. Follow Java conventions and be consistent!

```
jmovie.setSize(350, 150);
jmovie.setLocation(300,300);
jmovie.setVisible(true);

jmovie.add(south);
jmovie.add(west);
jmovie.add(center);
```

Component should be added to the dialog BEFORE the dialog is made visible.

So the code should be:

```
jmovie.add(south);
jmovie.add(west);
jmovie.add(center);

jmovie.setSize(350, 150);
jmovie.setLocation(300,300);
jmovie.setVisible(true);
```

You should be using `pack()` instead of setVisible(...). This will allow all the components to be displayed at their preferred size.

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
```

Also, you should not be create a JFrame. The parameter you want to pass to the JDialog, is the current visible JFrame.

So in your ActionListener you can get the current frame with logic like:

```
Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent( btnMAdd );
```

Now when you create your dialog you pass the window as a parameter:

```
JMovie ne = new JMovie(window);
```

and you use this value to specify the parent window of your dialog.

Comment: again is not showing anything in JMovie Dialog when i press the button just only the window . the explanation for the JMovie dialog is this

Comment: Layout explanation
- The whole dialog is using BorderLayout
- The South is a JPanel using FlowLayout that contains the two buttons
- The West is a JPanel using GridLayout (3x1). This panel includes the 3 JLabels that are
using right alignment.
- The Center is a JPanel using GrdLayout (3x1). Each position includes a JPanel using
FlowLayout with left alignment, and each JPanel includes one of the three JTextFields
seen above (using 15-wide for title, 10-wide for date and 6-wide for price). The JPanel
for the date also includes a disabled JLabel showing an input pattern

Comment: i mean i did everything he ask and again is not showing anything